# How to assign values from another dataframe to current dataframe based on a condition in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, assign

I want to assign values from a dataframe to another dataframe, based on the DatetimeIndex condition.

I have this dataframe: (FIRST)

```
date                importance
2006-12-05 10:35:00     HIGH
2006-12-13 02:40:00     LOW
```

And this dataframe: (SECOND)

```
index                     value
2006-12-05 08:03:01.985    6
2006-12-05 08:11:34.130    7
2006-12-05 08:20:05.959    6
2006-12-05 08:28:38.104    6
2006-12-05 08:37:02.995    6
2006-12-05 08:45:35.140    5
2006-12-05 08:54:06.969    6
2006-12-05 09:02:59.928    6
2006-12-05 09:11:32.072    6
2006-12-05 09:20:03.901    6
2006-12-05 09:28:36.046    5
2006-12-05 09:37:00.937    5
2006-12-05 09:45:33.082    6
2006-12-05 09:54:04.911    6
2006-12-05 10:02:04.889    6
2006-12-05 10:10:37.034    5
2006-12-05 10:19:08.863    6
2006-12-05 10:27:41.008    5
2006-12-05 10:36:04.953    5
2006-12-05 10:44:37.098    5
.
.
.
2006-12-13 02:06:00.898    1
2006-12-13 02:14:33.043    1
2006-12-13 02:23:04.872    1
2006-12-13 02:31:03.904    1
2006-12-13 02:39:36.048    1
2006-12-13 02:48:07.878    2
2006-12-13 02:56:40.022    5
2006-12-13 03:05:04.914    2
2006-12-13 03:13:37.058    3
2006-12-13 03:22:08.888    6
2006-12-13 03:31:03.108    1
2006-12-13 03:39:34.937    1
2006-12-13 03:48:07.081    1
2006-12-13 03:56:38.911    2
2006-12-13 04:05:04.117    3
```

The final result should be this:

```
index                      value    new_value
2006-12-05 08:03:01.985    6        
2006-12-05 08:11:34.130    7        
2006-12-05 08:20:05.959    6        
2006-12-05 08:28:38.104    6
2006-12-05 08:37:02.995    6
2006-12-05 08:45:35.140    5
2006-12-05 08:54:06.969    6
2006-12-05 09:02:59.928    6
2006-12-05 09:11:32.072    6
2006-12-05 09:20:03.901    6
2006-12-05 09:28:36.046    5
2006-12-05 09:37:00.937    5
2006-12-05 09:45:33.082    6
2006-12-05 09:54:04.911    6
2006-12-05 10:02:04.889    6
2006-12-05 10:10:37.034    5
2006-12-05 10:19:08.863    6
2006-12-05 10:27:41.008    5        
2006-12-05 10:36:04.953    5            HIGH
2006-12-05 10:44:37.098    5
.
.
.
2006-12-13 02:06:00.898    1
2006-12-13 02:14:33.043    1
2006-12-13 02:23:04.872    1
2006-12-13 02:31:03.904    1
2006-12-13 02:39:36.048    1            LOW
2006-12-13 02:48:07.878    2
2006-12-13 02:56:40.022    5
2006-12-13 03:05:04.914    2
2006-12-13 03:13:37.058    3
2006-12-13 03:22:08.888    6
2006-12-13 03:31:03.108    1
2006-12-13 03:39:34.937    1
2006-12-13 03:48:07.081    1
2006-12-13 03:56:38.911    2
2006-12-13 04:05:04.117    3
```

I tried this:

```
def getNearestDate(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))

items = second_df.index
for pivot in first_df.date:
    d = getNearestDate(items, pivot)
    print(d)
    second_df.loc[second_df.index == d, 'new_value'] = first_df.importance
```

it prints these dates that are the nearest ones:

```
2006-12-05 10:36:04.953000
2006-12-13 02:39:36.048000
```

so on these days it should put the values from the "importance".
Also, on the `new_value` column everything is NAN.

Could you help me please resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to keep the dates that correspond to the ones in the original dataframe:

```
items = second_df.index
dates = []

for pivot in first_df.date:
    dates.append(getNearestDate(items, pivot))
    
first_df['new_date'] = dates
```

As we no longer need them, we can drop the entire column:

```
first_df = first_df.drop(columns="date")
```

In order to make the merge work, we need to have index stated on both dataframes.

```
first_df.set_index("new_date", inplace =True)
```

The merge is done as follows:

```
second_df = second_df.merge(first_df, how = "left",left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Also, it is important to never let NaNs in the dataframe:

```
second_df.importance = second_df.importance.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the condition in loc
`second_df.index == d`
and it return true at index which satisfies condition, not the index.

Instead use
`second_df[second_df.index == d].index.values`

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit please? I don't really understand

Comment: second_df.loc[second_df[(second_df.index == d)].index.values, 'new_value']=first_df.importance , do this I hope now you get it

Answer (score 0):

You already have the mask you want with `second_df.index == d`. That produces a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) with values `True` where it is true, and `False` where it is false. You can `|=` multiple masks together to get all the rows that are `True` in any of the masks. Simply append that series to your second dataframe as the 'new_value' column.

```
mask = False
for pivot in first_df.date:
    mask |= second_df.index == getNearestDate(second_df.index, pivot)
second_df['new_value'] = mask
```

If you really want `'X'` and `''` to be aliases for `True` and `False`, you can also just apply a simple lambda to convert them before adding the series to the dataframe.

```
mask = False
for pivot in first_df.date:
    mask |= second_df.index == getNearestDate(second_df.index, pivot)
second_df['new_value'] = mask.apply(lambda x: 'X' if bool(x) else '')
```

EDIT:

If you want to take the `importance` value of the first dataframe, you can simply use the getNearestDate function to establish which rows need that value, and then merge them with the second dataframe.

```
first_df['index'] = first_df.apply(
    lambda x: getNearestDate(second_df.index, x.date),
    axis = 1,
    result_type = 'reduce'
)
second_df = second_df.merge(first_df, how='left', on='index')
```

Comment: I want to have the corresponding values from the first_df, not 'x'/' '  or True/False. "X" is actually a name, and it is ok to have NaN on the other remaining rows. What should I modify in this case?

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative approach that just merges the dataframes on the `index` column. It should fill all other rows with `NaN`s, and then you could rename the `importance` column to what you want, and drop the `date` column if you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use `reindex` and `merge`

```
# note the method and the tolerance. Change them to whatever works best for your actual data
new_df = df2.merge(df.reindex(df2.index, method='nearest', limit=1, tolerance='2T'),
                   left_index=True, right_index=True)


                         value importance
index                                    
2006-12-05 08:03:01.985      6        NaN
2006-12-05 08:11:34.130      7        NaN
2006-12-05 08:20:05.959      6        NaN
2006-12-05 08:28:38.104      6        NaN
2006-12-05 08:37:02.995      6        NaN
2006-12-05 08:45:35.140      5        NaN
2006-12-05 08:54:06.969      6        NaN
2006-12-05 09:02:59.928      6        NaN
2006-12-05 09:11:32.072      6        NaN
2006-12-05 09:20:03.901      6        NaN
2006-12-05 09:28:36.046      5        NaN
2006-12-05 09:37:00.937      5        NaN
2006-12-05 09:45:33.082      6        NaN
2006-12-05 09:54:04.911      6        NaN
2006-12-05 10:02:04.889      6        NaN
2006-12-05 10:10:37.034      5        NaN
2006-12-05 10:19:08.863      6        NaN
2006-12-05 10:27:41.008      5        NaN
2006-12-05 10:36:04.953      5       HIGH
2006-12-05 10:44:37.098      5        NaN
2006-12-13 02:06:00.898      1        NaN
2006-12-13 02:14:33.043      1        NaN
2006-12-13 02:23:04.872      1        NaN
2006-12-13 02:31:03.904      1        NaN
2006-12-13 02:39:36.048      1        LOW
2006-12-13 02:48:07.878      2        NaN
2006-12-13 02:56:40.022      5        NaN
2006-12-13 03:05:04.914      2        NaN
2006-12-13 03:13:37.058      3        NaN
2006-12-13 03:22:08.888      6        NaN
2006-12-13 03:31:03.108      1        NaN
2006-12-13 03:39:34.937      1        NaN
2006-12-13 03:48:07.081      1        NaN
2006-12-13 03:56:38.911      2        NaN
2006-12-13 04:05:04.117      3        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make these small changes hopefully it will work

```
loc=[]

    def getNearestDate(items, pivot):
        return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
    
    items = second_df.index
    for pivot in first_df.date:
        d = getNearestDate(items, pivot)
        loc.append(second_df.set_index('index').index.get_loc(d))
    
    ## Adding Data to your second df   
    second_df['importance']=[]
    for index,locations in enumerate(loc):
        df['importance'][int(location)]=first_df['importance'][index]
```